# modify joomla login with password validity period

Tags: joomla-3.x, login

I seek for advise how to modify the joomla login to set a validity period on the date for the password and make obligation for the (end)user  to reset the password with a new (safe) value; and how can a safe password be obliged

Comment: Welcome to JSE. While you wait for feedback, please take our [tour].

Comment: Password requirements can be configured in Users component configuration but for requiring regular password resets you'd need to write a plugin if such doesn't exist yet.

Comment: yes indeed, I was afraid that that would be needed; I'll look at it, thank you